# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

There are a ton of posts about this. I have looked at so many of them. Zero of the fixes seem to work.

```ruby
(main)> PayPal::SDK::Subscriptions::Plan.all
Request[post]: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
Request.body=grant_type=client_credentials  request.header={"User-Agent"=>"PayPalSDK/PayPal-Subscriptions-Ruby-SDK 0.3.1 (paypal-sdk-core 1.7.4; ruby 2.6.6p146-x86_64-linux;OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019)", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization"=>"Basic xxx"}
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock'
```

I have tried rvm 2.6.6, 2.7.0, and Debian Buster system ruby.

I followed all of these:
https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#troubleshooting-certificate-errors

I ran the automated SSL check and everything is roses:
https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#automated-ssl-check

```
root@19ab47f15632:/usr/src/app# curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby
Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:

Ruby:           2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems:       3.0.3
Bundler:        2.1.2
Compiled with:  OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
Loaded version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
SSL_CERT_FILE:  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
SSL_CERT_DIR:   /usr/lib/ssl/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...

Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       success ✅
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      success ✅
Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: success ✅

Hooray! This Ruby can connect to rubygems.org. You are all set to use Bundler and RubyGems.
```

I tried `gem update --system`, bundler is updated.

I tried curling the new CA to the location of ruby's default SSL file:

```
curl -fsSL curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o "$(ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE')"
```

I checked that my system's time was accurate (it's accurate to UTC).

I have no earthly idea what to do from here. The PayPal SDK subscription gem is using net/http under the covers because it relies on the core PayPal SDK gem. I tried increasing the loglevel to DEBUG but it prints out no additional details as it appears to fail in the same exact place, and I can't figure out where that failure actually is.

I'm at a loss. Short of disabling SSL verification, I don't know what to do. Is there some way to get more traceback / more error here to troubleshoot further? Using net/http directly against the PayPal API works fine (no SSL error). So it's something that happens after the initial request

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/varyonic/paypal-subscriptions-sdk-ruby? Because that relies on https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK which has been deprecated and is no longer supported. It also [bundles its own certificates](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/tree/master/data) which is probably the source of your troubles. (short answer: don't use unsupported & deprecated tools)

Comment: @anothermh unfortunately that is what I am using, and it makes sense if it's bundling its own certificates which is why the system certs are the problem.

It wasn't deprecated until very recently, and there's quite literally no replacement at this time.

Comment: That's a tough spot to be in. Hopefully knowing about the certs can lead you to some way of hacking a solution together. Good luck! If you figure something out I hope you'll share it as an answer here.

Answer (score 35):

Its possible to fix this by using the server's own CA file.

Try setting  `ssl_options: { ca_file: nil }`.

This causes the `paypal.crt` CA file bundled with the paypal-sdk gem to be ignored.

## For apps using PayPal::SDK.configure(...)

```
PayPal::SDK.configure(
  mode: ...,
  client_id: ...,
  client_secret: ...,

  # Deliberately set ca_file to nil so the system's Cert Authority is used,
  # instead of the bundled paypal.crt file which is out-of-date due to:
  # https://www.paypal.com/va/smarthelp/article/discontinue-use-of-verisign-g5-root-certificates-ts2240
  ssl_options: { ca_file: nil }
)
```

## For apps using a YAML config file

In `config/paypal.yml` or wherever your config file is located:

```
ssl_options:
  ca_file: null
```

Comment: Nice simple solution! Worked like a charm

Comment: Im here just to tell 2 things:
1) it worked
2) we need to start paying technical debt...

Answer (score 9):

I'm leaving this here, but the answer by RidingRails is what I consider "correct".  It is the proper solution to dealing with this longer-term, although the real solution is to move to PayPal's newer gem.

My answer below is to help you quickly get PayPal working again without having to push out an update to your code.

---

This is really ugly, as PayPal packages the certs with their gem.  To get up and running, you need to find the gem in your bundle and specifically find the file "paypal.crt".  At the end, you need to add the two certificates that are missing.  I am not going to copy/paste them here, but they are easily found.  Actually, they were already on my Ubuntu system in /etc/ssl/certs:

DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem

DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem

PayPal provides links here:

https://www.paypal.com/va/smarthelp/article/discontinue-use-of-verisign-g5-root-certificates-ts2240

Steps to fix:

1. Find the paypal.crt file in the version of the gem that you are using.  Here's what that looked like for me:

   cd app/production/shared/bundle

   find . -name paypal.crt

   At this point, I had a file in version 1.7.3 and 1.7.4 of the gem.  I'm using the 1.7.4 version, so I edited that file.
2. Add those two certificates to the bottom.  You should put the name of the certificate on a line, a line with "=" repeated to make a nice separator, and then the entire certificate including the BEGIN and END lines.
3. Restart your application.

This is not a long-term solution but will get you back running quickly.  Long term - upgrade to the new gem.

Comment: thank you Michael, I added a answer which is a small extension to your answer.

Comment: That’s a great fix.  I didn’t have time to be subtle with it :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is what we ended up doing on my team.

We added the 2 certs that Michael mentioned in

```
config/api.paypal.com.crt
```

Then in paypal.yml

```
 ssl_options:
    ca_file: config/api.paypal.com.crt
```

We left the Gem as is.  Initially we tore through the gem looking for answers but ultimately we left the gem as is and added the crt and updated yaml as show above.

Comment: You may be able to fix this by setting `ca_file` to `nil`, so the server's own CA file is used instead. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63305975/67834

Answer (score 8):

If you don't use `PayPal::SDK.configure`. In paypal.yml add

```
  ssl_options:
    ca_file: null
```

Comment: saved my day.... cleanest solution as far as i can see....

Answer (score 2):

As PayPal has changed TLS, so the easiest way (fastest) was to resolve as monkey patch. This patch says to use all default settings

```rb
module PayPal::SDK::Core
  module Util
    module HTTPHelper
      def configure_ssl(http)
        http.tap do |https|
          https.use_ssl = true
          https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
          add_certificate(https)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar but slightly less invasive solution than @kritik

```
module PayPal::SDK::Core::Util::HTTPHelper
  def default_ca_file
    nil # packaged CA file was out of date, use the system file
  end
end
```

This still allows you to change other SSL settings in initializers and only removes the default CA file.

You want to create a file in `config/initializers` and put the above code in it.